# Sprite sheet animation in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to animate a sprite sheet in Silverlight with C#.
I have made a lot of progress, the animations are working, but the problems is that they are not consistent between sheets. For example, I have these 3 sheets:

http://pokit.org/get/?8fc4562a63e6d7918789b0c84776a751.jpg

http://pokit.org/get/?ff4a073a307d50a7b950ac8dab26d60f.jpg

http://pokit.org/get/?053f25308d6a85a635913eb3f26f1c9f.jpg

The first two animate fine, but when the last one is animating I see parts of other frames, like this:

http://pokit.org/get/?9c0dc2266b0a84a2243daf4db5b7217a.jpg

This is the code I use to animate the sheets:(width and height are dimensions of particular frame which I determine earlier)

```
public class Animation
{
    private const int timeAnimationConstant = 10;
    private const int marginConstant = -11;
    private const int divisionConstant = 30;
    private const int frameTimeConstantMS = 150;

    public Animation() { 

    }

    /* Funkcija koja radi animaciju bilo čega - prima containter(Rectangle s forme), sheet koji animira, sirinu sheeta,
     * visinu sheeta, broje frameova u sheetu, i status(statička, dinamička), loop - da li je repeatat?, repetitions koliko puta? */
    public void Animate(Rectangle container, AnimationParams parameters) {
        // komit komentar
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush() { Stretch = Stretch.None, AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left, AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top };
        imageBrush.Transform = new CompositeTransform();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = parameters.Sheet; /* Ovdje pretpostavljam da smo po uzecu iz baze formirali BitmapImage tip i proslijedili */
        container.Margin = new Thickness(marginConstant, 0, marginConstant, 0);
        container.Width = parameters.Width + parameters.Width/divisionConstant;
        container.Height = parameters.Height + parameters.Height/(divisionConstant/3);
        container.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        container.Fill = imageBrush;
        container.RadiusX = 5;
        container.RadiusY = 5;

        // Storyboard za animaciju
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        if(parameters.Loop ) sb.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever; // odredjujem da li je na repeat

        ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames frm = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames(); // inicijaliziram frameove animacije
        frm.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

        int time = 0; // vrijeme kojim odredjujem trajanja frameova                     

        if (parameters.IsStatic == true)
        {
            // Statička animacija
            for (int j = 0; j < parameters.Repetitions; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < parameters.NumberOfFrames; i++)
                {

                    DiscreteObjectKeyFrame dokf = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame();
                    dokf.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time));
                    dokf.Value = -(i * parameters.Width);
                    frm.KeyFrames.Add(dokf);
                    time += parameters.NumberOfFrames * timeAnimationConstant;
                }
            }
            KidCode.Game.isAnimationComplete = true;
        }
        else { 
            // Dinamicka animacija

        }

        Storyboard.SetTarget(frm, container.Fill);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(frm, new PropertyPath("(ImageBrush.Transform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));
        sb.Children.Add(frm);
        sb.Begin();

    }
```

AnimationParams class, just in case:

```
public class AnimationParams
    {
        public BitmapImage Sheet { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfFrames { get; set;}
        public bool IsStatic { get; set; }
        public bool Loop { get; set; }
        public int Repetitions { get; set; }

        public AnimationParams(BitmapImage sheet, int width, int height, int numberOfFrames, bool isStatic, bool loop = false, int repetitions = 1) {

            Sheet = sheet;
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            NumberOfFrames = numberOfFrames;
            IsStatic = isStatic;
            Loop = loop;
            Repetitions = repetitions;
        }

    }
```

I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: What parameters are you using to call the `Animate` method? The issue is likely to be there

Comment: I  get the from a database, for example for this particular sheet(the one which is wrong) I use
width = 233, height = 218, numberofframes = 9

Comment: Why you set the height as 218, while the image has only 170?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the image itself. I tried to draw the border of each frame with the same width and it's impossible.

I tried 233 pixels width:
[image: 233 pixels]

151 pixels (suggested by KooKiz) also doesn't work:
[image]

So, I modified the the whole image, cut all the frames, set one width (181 pixels) and join them again. That's the result:
[image]

Here's my solution. Use the image below (you know, right click, save as...) and set width of the frame to 181 pixels:[image]

Interesting fact: the height of the image is 170 pixels, not 218...

Comment: No need to be condescending, as I used pokit to cut the image from screen, so it gave you a height of 170. 218 is the real height, and now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation code uses the width in parameter to know how to crop the sprites:

```
dokf.Value = -(i * parameters.Width);
```

The bogus tileset is 1365 pixels wide, for 9 frames. So you need to set a width of 1365 / 9 = 151 pixels.